# Functions imports after splitting a single JS file are no more aware of the object they take as parameter

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, openlayers-6

I have a more than 800 lines single JS file using [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) to create web map. It's definitely too much! The file is written in vanilla JavaScript.

It is simply structured as follow:

```
const function1 = (featurePassedFromFlask) {
  do stuff
  return someVectorLayers;
}

const function2 = (otherFeaturePassedFromFlask) {
  do stuff
  return aPoint;
}

const map = (vectorLayers, myPoint) => {
  do stuff to build the map, no returned value.
}

vectorLayers = function1(featurePassedFromFlask);
myPoint = function2(otherFeaturePassedFromFlask);

map(vectorLayers, myPoint);
```

As you can see, I have three main functions in there, so I decided to split it in three files, one for each function after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export:

File `function1.js`:

```
const function1 = (featurePassedFromFlask) {
  do stuff
  return someVectorLayers;
}
export { function1 };
```

File `function2.js`:

```
const function2 = (otherFeaturePassedFromFlask) {
  do stuff
  return aPoint;
}
export { function2 };
```

and file `map.js` with the remaining code + these two new lines at the top:

```
import { function1 } from './function1.js';
import { function2 } from './function2.js';
```

The "problem" is that in my Flask template `map.html` (jinja2) I only load the `map.js` file as:

```
<!-- Pass first result object from Python to JS here --> 
{% if resultsObjectFromRoute1 %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var featurePassedFromFlask = {{ resultsObjectFromRoute1|tojson }};
  </script>
{% endif %}

<!-- Pass second result object from Python to JS here --> 
{% if resultsObjectFromRoute2 %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var otherFeaturePassedFromFlask = {{ resultsObjectFromRoute2|tojson }};
  </script>
{% endif %}

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ol.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/map.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

The browser first complained: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` so I browse a little to figure out I have to change the last line to:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/map.js') }}" type="module"></script>
```

It doesn't complain anymore but not the page is not properly working:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable geom
```

I also tried to import my two functions files in `map.html` without any changes to the previous error message:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/function1.js') }}" type="module"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/function2.js') }}" type="module"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/map.js') }}" type="module"></script>
```

Maybe it would have worked if the function 1 and 2 didn't had to processed an argument, so I know I broke something related to that, because now those files "function1.js" and "function2.js" are no longer *aware* of the existence of the object they have to take into account as argument to the function defined in there. So how could I bring up that link again, just like when all was encapsulated in a single file?

ps: sorry for the probably bad - to very bad - wording, I'm not an expert in JS (that's also probably why I didn't succeed to find some helpful material).

Comment: Try to scratch the import/export syntax and use simple old basic import ``<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/functionN.js') }}"></script>`` (include the main file last, delete import/export keywords, do not wrap your code files into extra brackets). If it fixes the problem, the problem you are having is mess with contexes. If not, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: just to clarify, by "do not wrap your code files into extra brackets" I meant brackets enclosing your entire .js file. The reason I suggest this old approach is that browser will render those js file into same context so there would be no real difference between many or just one JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

There are two possibilities.

#### 1. as classical "type=application/javascript" imports within the HTML

Like @Kajbo suggested in the comments above, removing all export/import syntax and loading all the JS files in one by one in the HTML, with the main one (`map.js`) being loaded last in the template does work:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/function1.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/function2.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/map.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

but it **doesn't** work if they are loaded as "module", as I initially did.

The main disadvantage of this way of doing is that if you end up having 180 JS files, it meas 180 imports in your HTML. I was not very enthusiastic.

#### 2. as modern "type=module" imports within the HTML

In fact, I noticed that the error I had on `geom` was due to this line in my code:

```
geom = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
```

If this lazy way of declaring a variable worked before when loading the JS file with "type=application/javascript", it doesn't work when you load them as "type=module". Indeed, modules seem to be more ticklish and you really **have** to **declare** your variables properly now:

```
let geom = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
```

I've had many other similar mistakes, so I cleaned up my code with proper declarations and that's it! It's working now with the export/import ES6 logic, hence you can keep your HTML clean by *only* importing the main JS file (all JS logic stays in the JS files; that's much cleaner)!